# Is there any advice in the Buddhist scriptures that would help a leader balance a safe economy with people's concerns about sickness & death?

Tags: reference-request, the-buddha, death, society

1. Is there advice in the various Buddhist scriptures that a leader
   could use in this Coronavirus situation?
2. Is there advice in the Buddhist scriptures that a lay-person could
   use in this Coronavirus situation?
3. What are Buddhist leaders doing about this Coronavirus situation?

Comment: Why would people vote this question down? This question kicks ass imho.

Comment: It's a great question. I think it should be clear by now that authority is collapsing. S&P 500 is on a steady decline. People are very sceptical about large companies mostly due to the health issues that the vaccine has caused; its a global catastrophe that is largely being ignored! A decentralised society, where people are encouraged to generate their own resources, is a viable route forwards. However, greed has found a way to infest the virtues of looking after the planet through the guise of climate change. All just stories about nothing, of course! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddha taught to examine the cost (ādīnava) vs benefit (assāda) of worldly things. It follows world leaders must examine the benefits of their Covid measures (eg [here](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nvss/vsrr/covid_weekly/index.htm#Comorbidities)) versus the damaging consequences (eg [here](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-9276335/In-heartbreaking-pictures-human-face-cancer-epidemic-threatening-100-000-patients.html) or [here](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-9207927/Deadly-toll-scrapped-cancer-surgery-revealed.html?ito=amp_twitter_share-top) or [here](https://www.bbc.com/news/health-55863841) or [here](https://apnews.com/article/virus-outbreak-africa-ap-top-news-understanding-the-outbreak-hunger-5cbee9693c52728a3808f4e7b4965cbd)) of their Covid measures.

As for Buddhist leaders, most would be engaged in the passive political correctness most Buddhist leaders engage in today.

Comment: The first sentence ("The Buddha taught...") seems on-topic, but would be clearer with references to Buddhist doctrine, so a reader can assess how that (referenced doctrine) is applicable to the OP.

Comment: @Dhamma Dhatu Could you reference Buddhist scripture? 

Comment: @Dhamma Dhatu I didn't know you liked memes. I thought you were in a cave somewhere with a cellphone.  I see your thumbnail is related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

1. The government and leaders should provide just protection and security to its citizens. Basically, they should undertake the right measures to take care of their people.

From [DN 26](https://suttacentral.net/dn26/en/sujato):

> ‘But sire, what are the noble duties of a wheel-turning monarch?’
>
> ‘Well then, my dear, relying only on principle—honoring, respecting,
> and venerating principle, having principle as your flag, banner, and
> authority — provide just protection and security for your court,
> troops, aristocrats, vassals, brahmins and householders, people of
> town and country, ascetics and brahmins, beasts and birds. Do not let
> injustice prevail in the realm. Pay money to the penniless in the
> realm.

2. The lay Buddhist should play the role of a good patient and heed the advice of competent authorities.

From [Kucchivikara-vatthu](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/vin/mv/mv.08.26.01-08.than.html) of the Vinaya, the Buddha taught:

> "A sick person endowed with five qualities is easy to tend to: he does
> what is amenable to his cure; he knows the proper amount in things
> amenable to his cure; he takes his medicine; he tells his symptoms, as
> they actually are present, to the nurse desiring his welfare, saying
> that they are worse when they are worse, improving when they are
> improving, or remaining the same when they are remaining the same; and
> he is the type who can endure bodily feelings that are painful,
> fierce, sharp, wracking, repellent, disagreeable, life-threatening. A
> sick person endowed with these five qualities is easy to tend to.

3. Buddhist leaders should set a good example as the Dalai Lama had done (from [this article](http://www.phayul.com/2021/04/27/45556/)).

> The exiled Tibetan spiritual leader His Holiness the Dalai Lama has
> received his second dose of the Covishield vaccine at his residence on
> Monday, according to CTA run Tibet.net. He received the first jab on
> March 6 at Zonal hospital in Dharamshala.
>
> “The vaccine was administered by a medical team of Delek hospital led
> by Dr Tseten Dorjee, personal physician to His Holiness,” Tibet.net
> reported. The entire staff and security details of His Holiness,
> including those living in the residence, were also vaccinated, the
> report further stated. ...
>
> The Nobel laureate wrote that he has been following the alarming news
> of the pandemic across the world, especially including in India. “May
> I take this opportunity to express my deep appreciation for all the
> efforts that are being made to tackle this devastating pandemic,
> especially by those courageously working on the frontline. I pray that
> the pandemic threat will end soon,” he wrote. ...
>
> The Dalai Lama cancelled all his public engagements since February
> last year and engaged with the pubic through virtual platform for
> teachings and other interactive dialogues with students, Buddhist
> followers, and various organizations from all across the world. The
> Buddhist leader’s only public appearance since the lockdown was during
> his first Covishied jab at the local hospital last month, where he
> urged others to take the injection, “I want to share that more people
> should have the courage to take this injection.”

Comment: I'm not sure  that I would agree that there are any "competent" authorities.

Answer (score 0):

> What do you think, great king? Suppose a man, trustworthy and
> reliable, were to come to you from the east and on arrival would say:
> 'If it please your majesty, you should know that I come from the east.
> There I saw a great mountain, as high as the clouds, coming this way,
> crushing all living beings [in its path]. Do whatever you think should
> be done.' Then a second man were to come to you from the west... Then
> a third man were to come to you from the north... Then a fourth man
> were to come to you from the south and on arrival would say: 'If it
> please your majesty, you should know that I come from the south. There
> I saw a great mountain, as high as the clouds, coming this way,
> crushing all living beings. Do whatever you think should be done.' If,
> great king, such a great peril should arise, such a terrible
> destruction of human life — the human state being so hard to obtain —
> what should be done?"
>
> "If, lord, such a great peril should arise, such a terrible
> destruction of human life — the human state being so hard to obtain —
> what else should be done but Dhamma-conduct, right conduct, skillful
> deeds, meritorious deeds?"
>
> [SN 3.25](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn03/sn03.025.than.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following "advice" seems suitable for all of the people mentioned in your question. Translation and opening comment by Ven. Ṭhānissaro.

> Being Consummate - Sampadā Sutta  ([AN 5:130](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/AN/AN5_130.html#:%7E:text=This%20discourse%20serves%20as%20a%20strong%20reminder%20not%20to%20break%20the%20precepts%20even%20for%20the%20sake%20of%20people%20or%20things%20one%20holds%20dear.))
>
> This discourse serves as a strong reminder not to break the precepts
> even for the sake of people or things one holds dear.
>
> ---
>
> “Monks, there are these five kinds of loss. Which five? Loss of
> relatives, loss of wealth, loss through disease, loss in terms of
> virtue, loss in terms of views. It’s not by reason of loss of
> relatives, loss of wealth, or loss through disease that beings—with
> the break-up of the body, after death—reappear in a plane of
> deprivation, a bad destination, a lower realm, hell. It’s by reason of
> loss in terms of virtue and loss in terms of views that beings—with
> the break-up of the body, after death—reappear in a plane of
> deprivation, a bad destination, a lower realm, hell. These are the
> five kinds of loss.
>
> “There are these five ways of being consummate. Which five? Being
> consummate in terms of relatives, being consummate in terms of wealth,
> being consummate in terms of freedom from disease, being consummate in
> terms of virtue, being consummate in terms of views. It’s not by
> reason of being consummate in terms of relatives, being consummate in
> terms of wealth, or being consummate in terms of freedom from disease
> that beings—with the break-up of the body, after death—reappear in a
> good destination, a heavenly world. It’s by reason of being consummate
> in virtue and being consummate in terms of views that beings—with the
> break-up of the body, after death—reappear in a good destination, a
> heavenly world. These are the five ways of being consummate.”